# Работа с WITH в SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Всем доброго времени суток!**

Имеется SQL код:

```
WITH contractor_ids AS
(
    SELECT id FROM contractors WHERE count IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
)

DELETE FROM properties WHERE contractor_id IN (SELECT id FROM contractor_ids)
GO

--WITH contractor_ids AS
--(
--  SELECT id FROM contractors WHERE count IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
--)

DELETE FROM contractors WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM contractor_ids)
GO
```

Почему, если оставить комментарий, то код не работает? У WITH есть какая-то зона видимости? И как в таком случае поступить?

Comment: contractor_ids - объект не определён, так как вы его закоментировали. go - это разделитель батчей (группа команд, выполняемых сервером вместе).

Comment: *У WITH есть какая-то зона видимости?* WITH - это такая же составная часть запроса, как и любая другая. И неудивительно, что она, как и любая другая часть запроса, не видна в другом запросе. *как в таком случае поступить?* Использовать табличную переменную либо временную таблицу.

Comment: PS. В данном случае использование WITH бессмысленно. И сервер почти наверняка интегрирует его в запрос.

Answer (score 1):

GO - разделитель пакетов, это почти тоже самое, что на одной вкладке написать CTE, а на другой вкладке пытаться обратиться к ней.

В данном случае GO между запросом нужно удалить/закомментировать.

Код раздутый, тут достаточно 2х строк:

```
DELETE FROM properties WHERE contractor_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10
DELETE FROM contractors WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```